# restructuring Nodejs Express Project

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller

I want to restructure Nodejs Express Project that contains v1 and v2 folders inside routes directory.
when restructuring the code to MVC approach, should i have MVC structure for v1 and another MVC structure under v2?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally controllers should be versioned as `v1`, `v2`, etc., as they will contain your application logic, which is going to change from time to time, and you'll need to support users using the logic of older version of your application (fallback compatibility).

Models will contain schema for records stored in your database, which should remain consistent across all versions of your controllers. Therefore it should remain outside of your `v1`, `v2`, etc. (Like, User will contain same fields regardless of the difference in application logic versions). Changes in models are generally not drastic, as you'll have to define them in a way which doesn't require huge changes later on. In case of a drastic change, you'll have to update the logic across all versions of your controllers accordingly.

Views, can either be versioned or not, depending upon whether you'd like to serve separate views depending upon api version.

Overall, the project structure may look like this

```
src/
  models/
    ModelA.js
    ModelB.js
    ...
  routes/
    v1/
      index.js
      ...
    v2/
      ...
  views/
    index.ejs
    ...
  server.js
  package.json
```